# Proper way to handle multiple QNetworkRequests

Tags: c++, qt, qnetworkaccessmanager

im grabbing url's from a list and then sending each to a QNetworkRequest and recieving the HTML back to process. I however have thousands of requests to process. So my application kept hanging until i stopped it from producing all these requests at once.

Is this the rite way to handle the que for a great number of requests?
I tried using a Qqueue of Urls, which i would then link to a SLOT which was triggered after each QNetworkReply reponse.

Create the job list and add to que

```
QQueue<QString> jobs;
for (int i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++){
    QString pageUrl = url + "&page=" + QString::number(i);
    jobs.enqueue(pageUrl);
}

qDebug() << "Total Jobs : " << jobs.count() << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    processQueue();
}
```

then inside the getHtml function

```
QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    QNetworkRequest *getHtmlRequest = new QNetworkRequest(pageUrl);
    getHtmlRequest = new QNetworkRequest(url);
    getHtmlRequest->setRawHeader( "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686 (x86_64); "
                               "en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008070206 Firefox/3.0.1" );
    getHtmlRequest->setRawHeader( "charset", "utf-8" );
    getHtmlRequest->setRawHeader( "Connection", "keep-alive" );
    connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(replyGetPageHtmlFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
    connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(processQueue()));
    manager->get(*getHtmlRequest);
```

which triggers

```
void checkNewArrivalWorker::processQueue(){
if (jobs.isEmpty()){
    qDebug() << "Jobs Completed" << endl;
    emit finished();
} else {
    QString pageUrl = jobs.dequeue();
    QString pageNumber = pageUrl.mid(pageUrl.indexOf("page=") + 5);
    getHtml(pageUrl, pageNumber);
}
}
```

Comment: The general approach makes sense. Although I'd start N jobs in parallel instead of just one. Some issues: 1) You leak QNetworkRequest objects by creating them on the heap and not deleting them. Create them on the stack instead. 2) Make sure to call deleteLater() on the reply objects to have them deleted. 3) checkNewArrivalWorker's finished() might be emitted before  the last replyGetPageHtmlFinished is executed - just in case that's a problem.

Comment: Hi There thanks for your reply. I'm still a student so am trying to understand what you mean by this so please correct me if i'm wrong. When you say create on the stack , i should use

    QNetworkRequest getPageRequest = QNetworkRequest(url);

instead of 

    QNetworkRequest *getPageRequest = new QNetworkRequest(url);

2) to call delete layer on reply objects i just add
    reply->deleteLater();   after i have gotten the desired html from the reply..

and 3)  yes i see this now how that finished() could be called before the last few requests so i will figure that out also.

Comment: stack vs. heap: Yes, that's what I meant